# Error received when initializing a ViteJS

Tags: npm, vite

When I run the command below in Gitbash:

$ npm create vite@latest

I recevice the following error:

```
$ npm create vite@latest
'Company\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1415fee72ff6294b\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\create-vite\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.2
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Media4th&Company\desktop\vite
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-vite

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Media4th&Company\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-30T00_59_40_173Z-debug-0.log
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Try using a path without special characters (i.e. the "&" sign): npm ERR! path C:\Users\Media4th&Company\desktop\vite. Does that help?

Comment: @JamesHibbard The same error occurs on paths without special characters

Comment: Could Gitbash be problematic? Try switching to a different terminal like Command Prompt or PowerShell to run these commands. Same result?

Comment: Also, probably not related, but try cleaning the npm cache: `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: i use different terminal but same error and i did `npm cache clean -f` but nothing change

Comment: Tricky. What does the debug log say (specified in the npm error you posted)?

Comment: I solved it. It was resolved by removing the nvm installation file. Thank you

Comment: Oh good. Which nvm file would that be?